# Перевод из float в decimal.bits

Tags: c#

```
using System;
class HelloWorld {
  static void Main() {
    float value = 123.34634534f;
int[] bits1 = decimal.GetBits(value);
        Console.WriteLine("Value 1:\noriginal.bits[0] = {0}; \noriginal.bits[1] = {1};\noriginal.bits[2] = {2};\noriginal.bits[3] = {3};\n", 
         (uint)bits1[0], 
         (uint)bits1[1], 
         (uint)bits1[2], 
         (uint)bits1[3]);
  }
}
```

Как правильно это делать? Для int value все работает, а для float нет.

Comment: Написал (decimal)value в GetBits, заработало